# enable the button only if condition is valid

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I want to validate the email field with specific condition. It should only enable the submit button if the email ID typed in the text field
is ending with gmail.com(ex.,xyz@gmail.com).

Demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/lVCGIr3rSajseLeC5hUx?p=preview

Sample code:

```
<input type="text" name="user" ng-model="shareSelectionFormFields.user" required>

<span class="error" ng-show="myForm.user.$dirty && myForm.user.$invalid">
    <span ng-show="myForm.user.$error.required">Username is required. 
    </span>
</span>

<input type="submit" 
       ng-disabled="(myForm.user.$dirty && myForm.user.$invalid) ||
                    (myForm.email.$dirty && myForm.email.$invalid) ||
                    (myForm.recipientEmail.$dirty &&
                     myForm.recipientEmail.$invalid) ||
                    myForm.$invalid" />
```

The above code will enable the submit button if it is a valid email ID, but how to restrict it to enable the submit button only if email ID typed is ending with gmail.com

Any inputs?

I tried using the below script but regular expression only tells legal characters in email address.

```
function ValidateEmail(mail) 
{
 if (/^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,3})+$/.test(myForm.emailAddr.value))
  {
    return (true)
  }
    alert("You have entered an invalid email address!")
    return (false)
}
```

Comment: your question is how to have a regex for validating only strings ending with @gmail.com or how to bind this function to a button for disabling it when the validation fails?

Comment: The form is missing the `email` input and the `recipientEmail` input.

Comment: @georgeawg please have a look at my answer. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`ng-pattern`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngPattern) and set the regex `/^[A-Za-z0-9._%+-]+@gmail.com$/` their.

So your `input` will be:

```
<input type="email" name="email" ng-model="shareSelectionFormFields.email"
       ng-pattern="/^[A-Za-z0-9._%+-]+@gmail.com$/" required />
```

Below is working demo code:

http://plnkr.co/edit/UtSPI5pgXbqc5QUwfWI8?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

In angularjs you can use the directive `ng-pattern` in order to match patterns and validate the field.

Inside your regex simply change the end of the regex in order to include only @gmail.com.

The final code should be something like this:

```
<input type="text" name="user" ng-model="shareSelectionFormFields.user"
       ng-pattern="^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@gmail.com" required />
```

And then you can have a button specifying the `ng-disabled` directive depending on the validation of the field, so something like the following:

```
<button ng-disabled="myForm.user.$invalid">SUBMIT</button>
```

Here the link to the `ng-pattern` doc:

[ng-pattern documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngPattern)